# Paypal Authentication/Authorization Failed on Store

Tags: magento2, paypal, paypal-express, magento2.4.3

We have a Adobe Commerce website with 3 store-views FR EN and US.

While placing the order from storefront with **PayPal** only on US store I am getting this error **`Username/Password is incorrect (#10002: Authentication/Authorization Failed).`** I am able to place the orders successfully on FR and EN store with PayPal.

So far we have regenerated the **PayPal** credentials and try with new Credentials but the result is the same. Below are the request and response from Payment Logs.

```
 array (
  'url' => 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp',
  'SetExpressCheckout' => 
  array (
    'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
    'AMT' => '58.67',
    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
    'RETURNURL' => 'https://<base_url>/en_us/paypal/express/return/',
    'CANCELURL' => 'https://<base_url>/en_us/paypal/express/cancel/',
    'INVNUM' => 'INVOICE#',
    'SOLUTIONTYPE' => 'Sole',
    'GIROPAYCANCELURL' => 'https://<base_url>/en_us/paypal/express/cancel/',
    'GIROPAYSUCCESSURL' => 'https://<base_url>/en_us/checkout/onepage/success/',
    'BANKTXNPENDINGURL' => 'https://<base_url>/en_us/checkout/onepage/success/',
    'SUBJECT' => 'MERCHANT EMAIL ID',
    'SHIPPINGAMT' => '21.67',
    'ITEMAMT' => '37.00',
    'TAXAMT' => '0.00',
    'L_NUMBER0' => NULL,
    'L_NAME0' => 'Perfumed Candle Warm Honey',
    'L_QTY0' => 1,
    'L_AMT0' => '18.50',
    'L_NUMBER1' => NULL,
    'L_NAME1' => 'Perfumed Candle Frosted Birch',
    'L_QTY1' => 1,
    'L_AMT1' => '18.50',
    'BUSINESS' => NULL,
    'NOTETEXT' => NULL,
    'EMAIL' => 'username@example.com',
    'FIRSTNAME' => 'user',
    'LASTNAME' => 'name',
    'MIDDLENAME' => NULL,
    'SALUTATION' => NULL,
    'SUFFIX' => NULL,
    'COUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
    'STATE' => 'NJ',
    'CITY' => 'Lakehurst',
    'STREET' => 'Batchelor Officer Quarters',
    'ZIP' => '08733-1925',
    'PHONENUM' => '12313123123',
    'SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
    'SHIPTOSTATE' => 'NJ',
    'SHIPTOCITY' => 'Lakehurst',
    'SHIPTOSTREET' => 'Batchelor Officer Quarters',
    'SHIPTOZIP' => '08733-1925',
    'SHIPTOPHONENUM' => '12313123123',
    'SHIPTOSTREET2' => 'A Stevens Circle Dr',
    'STREET2' => 'A Stevens Circle Dr',
    'SHIPTONAME' => 'user name',
    'ADDROVERRIDE' => 1,
    'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'BUTTONSOURCE' => 'Magento_2_B2B',
  ),
  'response' => 
  array (
    'TIMESTAMP' => '2022-11-16T18:30:42Z',
    'CORRELATIONID' => '9c2fc8c96233d',
    'ACK' => 'Failure',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'BUILD' => '57889147',
    'L_ERRORCODE0' => '10002',
    'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => 'Authentication/Authorization Failed',
    'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => 'Username/Password is incorrect',
    'L_SEVERITYCODE0' => 'Error',
  ),
)
```

We were using a custom extension to configure **USA PayPal** merchant account for **US store**.So we tried and disable the module and use the same credential and Configured with the **Magento Paypal** module, the results are the same Successful Payment on EN and FR Failed on US store

We start experiencing this from a couple of days ago and we didn't commit any changes on our website it seem to be an issue from PayPal and we are also in contact with PayPal support.

Does anyone have encountered this issue?
Any Recommendation if someone have similar issue?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone faced the issue. Paypal reported back, that the API credentials were never the issue but at some point a couple of days ago since the issue was reported, the master email associated to the PayPal US account was removed from their system.
So after adding the account email now the issue is resolved.